# Is this likely to be asbestos in the ceiling above my bathroom?

Tags: asbestos

The ceiling fan in my bathroom is playing up, so I removed it.

Looking inside the roof above the hole I saw the following:

[image]

It looked like a big clump of dust so I grabbed it and it felt quite soft.  I am probably being paranoid but is there any chance this could be asbestos?  I know soft asbestos is used as insulation but would I find it so close to the plasterboard like that?

The house was built in 1964 (in Australia).

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell from the photo, but it looks like long, man-made fibers which is not a common form of asbestos in residential homes.  The common form is vermiculite.  I have a home built in 1965 (in the US) and it had "rock wool" batting which I was concerned about, so I did a fair amount of research.  [This article](http://www.oldhouseweb.com/blog/does-some-attic-insulation-contain-asbestos/) helped me feel better.  The only way to know for sure is to send a sample to get visually inspected at a lab.  I had some plaster checked and it was not expensive.